# Tor daemon is frozenn ( Rend stream is 120 seconds late.)

Tags: configuration, circuit, torsocks

Good day, i have some problem with tor daemon on Linux.
i use tor daemon to proxy access some site, but periodic tor is frozen, and can't proxy requests.
in logs i seee only this.

```
Oct 07 02:29:54 Tor[6278]: Rend stream is 120 seconds late. Giving up on address '[scrubbed].onion'.
Oct 07 02:32:27 Tor[6278]: Rend stream is 120 seconds late. Giving up on address '[scrubbed].onion'.
Oct 07 02:32:31 Tor[6278]: Rend stream is 120 seconds late. Giving up on address '[scrubbed].onion'.
```

i use default tor configuration and not change torrc.
how can fix that?
or tell me please maybe have can i tack this via Tor Control.
if restart tor daemon all starts normaly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the circuit to the dot-onion is suffering. You have a simple 3-step checklist to follow to ensure the things are working right:

1. **Is your ORPort available from outside?** Tor performs this check at startup - and not without a reason. Having it available makes your node integrated into the network in a **greatly higher** level
2. **Has your network stack been tuned?** Tor has a very moderate requirements, **but** to make it work faster you have to *increase* the number of network connections, file descriptors, buffer sizes and *decrease* the connection termination timeouts, so it will be no tarpit attack vectors
3. **Do you run and use bridges?** If you're not using them - you should run one! It's not an obligation to make it public, but even cooperating with your friends to bridge each other - it **really** helps!

Comment: Good day @Alexey Vesnin, thx for answer.
1. i am not provide relay.
2. yep, stack is tunned. sysctl and security(file limit)
3. nope, direct connect.

Comment: try to provide relay - it's not the same as the exit, so no risks for you, but the ORPort available makes a network integration a way better - give it a try! The integration goes up not in an instant move, so give it some time, let's see what happens in your case. And - if it's possible - just leave Tor running for as long as possible and try the request you're making from time to time